# react-beautiful-dnd - how to extract data about order of columns

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-beautiful-dnd

I implemented nice looking and nicely behaving table with `react-beautiful-dnd`.
https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd

It works, meaning I can move columns around, changing their places.

**But how do I extract ordering of columns? I need that in a list/Array, or something like that**

Basically everything is placed inside `DragDropContext`, here is the source i based everything on:
https://codesandbox.io/s/1o02rxrvoj?file=/EnhancedTableHead.js

Comment: Doesn't the `columnData` array store the ordering of the columns? Is there something extra you need?

Comment: Jesus, you are right. Silly me. Thank you. Case closed.

There is that function `onDragEnd()` and inside there is call to `reorder()`